# Pegar caminho de pastas e arquivos (ao mesmo tempo) com Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialog, electron

Bom dia galera. Gostaria de saber se tem como pegar o caminho de arquivos e pastas (ao mesmo tempo) usando o Electron. Estou usando o 'dialog.showOpenDialog()', mas ele retorna ou só pastas ou só arquivos, preciso que ele retorne ambos.

Answer (score 1):

Na [documentação](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) menciona que não é possível selecionar ficheiros e diretórios ao mesmo tempo.

> Note: On Windows and Linux an open dialog can not be both a file selector and a directory selector, so if you set properties to ['openFile', 'openDirectory'] on these platforms, a directory selector will be shown.